# Unity. iOS. Сумасшествие с изображениями

Tags: ios, unity3d

Не знаю как это по другому назвать. Но вот как выглядит игра в плеере юнити и запущенная под виндовс:

[image: Игра запущенная под windows]

А вот так это чудесно выглядит при компиляции и запуске на iOS
[image: Игра запущенная под iOS]

В целом игра это большой canvas, почти все объекты это либо image, либо rawImage

Answer (score 1):

Довольно странно делать игру в канвасе.

Ну да ладно.

Все дело, на сколько я понимаю, в настройках канваса и разном разрешении девайсов. Поиграйтесь с настройками самого канваса и с настройками анкоров(уверен что проблема в первую очередь именно в них) обьектов или же начни делать игру так как она должна делатся -- в самом вьюпорте. Без канваса :) А то занимаешся извращениями....

Канвас предназначен для деланья менюх, а не игр :)

Comment: Я просто думал, что канвас быстрее будет, так как сама игра по сути большая менюха с кнопками ) Но проблема решалась по другому. Это баг Юнити, он был в багтрекере и его должны были закрыть в новой версии